# Normalization: Should common columns of two tables be pulled out into a third table?

Tags: database-design, best-practices, normalization

Should I further normalize my current design to eliminate redundancies?

I have the following tables:

`empl`: standard user table

`empl_cat`: employee "category"

`empl_admin_cat`: administrative "category"

Both of the category tables have a many-to-one relationship back to the `empl` table.

The `employee category` represents the categorization of the employee within the company.

The `administrative category` represents that employee's administrative oversight (if applicable) over other employees.

The tables are defined like this (irrelevant columns have been omitted):

```
empl (
    empl_id int PK,
    ...
)

empl_cat (
    empl_cat_id int PK,
    empl_id int FK,
    eff_date date,
    base_id int FK,
    eqp_id int FK,
    pos_id int FK
)

empl_admin_cat (
    admin_cat_id int PK,
    empl_id int FK,
    co_id int FK,
    base_id int FK,
    eqp_id int FK,
    pos_id int FK
)
```

I considered using a single table with a `type` column, but decided against it because they logically represent two different things, and while 3 of their columns are the same (`base_id`, `eqp_id`, `pos_id`), they each have one additional column (`eff_date` and `co_id`).  Was this the right decision?

Would it be worthwhile creating another table that has an autoincrement Primary Key which holds all possible variations of `base_id`/`eqp_id`/`pos_id`, with the `empl_cat` and `empl_admin_cat` tables referencing the appropriate record in this new table instead of having their own `base_id`/`eqp_id`/`pos_id` columns?

Edit: The `base_id`, `eqp_id` and `pos_id` fields represent their "base of operations", "operating equipment", and "position". For example, SFO/777/Captain. The `co_id` in the `empl_admin_cat` represents a company.  `eff_date` in `empl_cat` is an effective date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 options

1. Do nothing
2. Superkey/subtype, that is put the common fields into empl
3. Change to a self referencing table to build a hierarchy

Now,

- Option 2 is similar to what you've described (mostly)
- Option 3 is where you'd use a recursive CTE

However, I can't help thinking that Option 3 or some variety would be better. Perhaps some more info about what the columns mean? (Personally I don't abbreviate column names because the names are opaque)

Comment: I updated my question with some info on what the columns are. Can you go into a little more detail about what you mean with option 3? I have used self-referencing tables before (and recursive CTEs), but I do not understand how it could apply to this particular situation.